# Can you have a SQL where clause on a calculated field

Tags: sql

Is there any way to do something like this:

```
 select Name, sum(Exceptions) exceptions from Results i
 where exceptions > 0
 group by (Name)
```

where I am filtering out all of the records that are 0 in a calculated sum field

I am getting an error "Invalid use of an aggregate function"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Exceptions) AS exceptions
FROM Results AS r
GROUP BY (Name)
HAVING SUM(Exceptions) > 0
```

Comment: What SQL engine(s) let you apply a condition to an aggregate result in this way?

Comment: It doesn't, it looked off after posting, so went to confirm and saw my mistake. I've since corrected the answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
select Name, sum(Exceptions) exceptions from Results i
group by (Name)
HAVING SUM(Exceptions) > 0
```

HAVING is a where clause that applies to the *aggregated* rows of the results set.